# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`'

Tags: php, html

I'm working through some PHP tutorials and I've come across some code that doesn't seem to be working, perhaps there is a missing bracket but I can't work out where.

(Sorry for the picture, I couldn't get the code pasted properly for some reason)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at line 12,you have an extra ' hanging there

Comment: This is why Notepad++, while right for some people is wrong for others. You need something with live syntax-verification; look at PHPStorm or NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is caused because in line 12 you have "`":

```
10|  } else { // must be equivalent
11|     $message = "Well done!";
12|  `}
```

use this instead:

```
10|  } else { // must be equivalent
11|     $message = "Well done!";
12|  }
```